# Count specific array values with same part

Tags: php, arrays

I found a lot of samples how to count positions or occurrences in an arrays but actualy this doesnt solve my problem.

My Array looks like:

```
$foo = array(
          "foo"=>"bar",
          "bar"=>"foo",
          "hello"=>"world",
          "world"=>"hello",
          "grT1"=>"A",
          "grT2"=>"B",
          "grT3"=>"C",
          "grT4"=>"D",
          "grT5"=>"E",
          "gr1"=>2,
          "gr2"=>0,
          "gr3"=>,
          "gr4"=>5,
          "gr5"=>
)
```

What I want to achive is to count how many `gr{i}` are in my array.

The thing is, I dont want the count `grT{i}`. So the result for this sample should be **5**.

`array_count_values` does not help me in this case.

My Try atm is:

```
$count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($foo);$i++){
    if(array_key_exists("gr".$i, $foo)){
        $count++
    }
}
```

is this the only way to do this ? or is there a nicer way ?

**EDIT:** *Since I need the result for a loop (for) I would like to get rid of this loop.*

Comment: Maybe clean up the loop with `foreach` loop. `while` is unnecessary here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_reduce() will do the job

```
$count = array_reduce(array_keys($foo), function($c, $k){
  return preg_match('/^gr\d+$/', $k) ? ++$c : $c;
}, 0);
```

Comment: But my answer is more optimised because I am not returning array only right number and do not have count after that elements of that array. I am telling it only as a explain not complain ;)

Comment: Accepted your answere because in 10k requests its 0.02 sec. faster :)

Comment: of course I do. In my case I need all performance I can get :)

Comment: Did you check your solution with loop? How fast was that?

Comment: Actually its the same speed, sometimes its even 0.01 faster but there is the source length what makes me feel uncomfortable :D

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for your tests :)

Comment: on 100.000 its 0.24 for loop, yours is 0.31 and the other ones is 0.35

Comment: If you use this code `return substr($k, 0, 2) == 'gr' &&  substr($k, 2, 1) !== 'T'? ++$c : $c;` it will be even faster.

Comment: For me it is faster about 0.1s than code with `preg_match` for 100.000 its

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114250/discussion-between-dwza-and-nospor).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using `array_keys` and `array_filter` functions:

```
$count = count(array_filter(array_keys($foo), function($v){
    return preg_match('/^gr\d+?/',$v);
}));
// $count is 5
```